# How to format a number after user enter input in input box in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Can anybody tell How to format a number after user enter input in input box in angular js.I have text box suppose if user enter 123456

I need to format like this
123,456

Thanks

Comment: And what have you done so far ?

Comment: i think you are using for telephone no. format ??

Comment: You have reputation enough to know that you must post a little piece of code or some info about what you have done and why you are having problems doing it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `filter` to achieve this:

```
{{ number_expression | number:fractionSize}}
```

Here:

```
number: Number to format.
fractionSize: Number of decimal places to round the number to. If this is 
not provided then the fraction size is computed from the current locale's number
```

formatting pattern. In the case of the default locale, it will be 3.

[Refer Angular Docs for the same](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number).

See the following Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EDAMlk7Qk3urMG0JEsSI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use a directive like this:

```
define(['angular'], function () {
    angular.module("scDecimals", [])
        .directive('decimals', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                    ctrl.$formatters.push(function (data) {
                        //convert data from model format to view format
                        var decimalPlaces = 1;
                        if (attrs["decimalplaces"]) {
                            var decPlaces = parseInt(attrs["decimalplaces"]);
                            if (!isNaN(decPlaces)) {
                                decimalPlaces = attrs["decimalplaces"];
                            }
                        }
                        var result = $filter('number')(data, decimalPlaces); //converted
                        return result;
                    });

                ctrl.$parsers.push(function (data) {
                    //convert data from view format to model format
                    var result = parseFloat(data);
                    return result; //converted
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
});
```

With this you convert data from the view to the model and vice versa. Especially helpful if the user enters a 40 and you want to display it as 40.0. The way this is achieved is by using $formatters and $parsers functionality from angularjs - read more in the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Usage example:

```
<input type="text" data-decimals decimalplaces="2" ng-model="variable.value" />
```